The USB Drive not listed but recongnized
So this happened since i installed fresh debian, and after setup was done, i plugged in both my USB drives, but only one of them showed up in file manager, but if i check gnome-disk and lsusb it shows up.


Look the image 2, only one shows up

I forget to mention, i have two of them

well, then edit your question to include that information, instead of just commenting on it :)

also, tell us about whether it's always the same one that doesn't show up, or whether this only happens when both are connected at the same time? We can't read minds, you need to give us all information that you have. Also, for the one that is detected but doesn't show up: does it appear in lsblock after you plugged it in?

Whether you plug it all in or not, it still doesn't appear, the drive isn't blocked, but the other drives are safe, and I definitely can't find out anything other than what I mentioned.

EDIT your question. DON'T just comment, please!

And, while [edit]ing to answer and clarify what has been requested 2 comments above, make sure to also inform how the drives have been formatted, i.e., what filesystems are at play here. If I were to guess the ~64GB is exFAT, isn't it?
